# how to extract the ('uid') value using regex or grep from this json?

Tags: json, regex, grep

I have below API JSON response:

https://gist.github.com/mzaboss/944d30a1c29796cbe8dbb6aa95d7e20e

I'd like to extract the values of `'uid': '6904989037985481733'`.

Example:

```
6904989037985481733
6775449343043519493
6864191257082741765
6790990270277551110
6846402706555601926
```

etc

I've tried `cat ids.txt | grep 'uid'`, with failed attempted.

How to make an accurate grep? please

Thank you,
regards.

Comment: Looks like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) could help instead.

Comment: @sp00m command please?

Comment: Please add your JSON to your question (no links, no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus https://gist.github.com/mzaboss/944d30a1c29796cbe8dbb6aa95d7e20e its here.

Comment: The JSON doesn't seem valid. Can you sort out any errors with https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

jq is the best tool to use for json but given that the json from the link doesn't seem to be formatted correctly, you can use the following to get the UID entries:

```
grep -Eo "'uid': '[[:alnum:]]+'" file.json | cut -d "'" -f 4
```

Output the uid keys and entries with grep and then extract just the values by using cut.